# How to put SAML token directly into JAX-WS service without calling STSClient

Tags: java, cxf, jax-ws, wsdl2java, jax-ws-customization

Last year I made JAX-WS client for a web service in [this link](https://3pt.portal.usi.gov.au/Service/v2/UsiService.svc)

This webservice use a [STS service](https://thirdparty.authentication.business.gov.au/R3.0/vanguard/S007v1.2/Service.svc) to get SAML token and use it to access main webservice. I use wsdl2java of apache cxf to generate JAX-WS client for this webservice. Everything was just fine.

Recently they have updated their STS service endpoint. [This](https://thirdparty.authentication.business.gov.au/R3.0/vanguard/S007v1.3/Service.svc) new STS service endpoint. Which has different signature and digest algorithm. It has some extra element in request body.

I tried to modify current code so that it support new STS service. But my code is sending same RequestSecurityToken request.I mean it does not adopt for new requirement. I tried to adopt this but I could not do that.

New STS service required http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256 as new signature method and http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256 as new digest algorithm. Plus it required following element in request body:

```
    <tr:ActAs xmlns:tr="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200802">
<v13:RelationshipToken xmlns:v13="http://vanguard.business.gov.au/2016/03" ID="1bc9a44e-dccd-49e2-8f29-40d7b1257325">
<v13:Relationship v13:Type="OSPfor">
<v13:Attribute v13:Name="SSID" v13:Value="1234567895"/>
</v13:Relationship>
<v13:FirstParty v13:Scheme="uri://abr.gov.au/ABN" v13:Value="27809366375"/>
<v13:SecondParty v13:Scheme="uri://abr.gov.au/ABN" v13:Value="89567587874"/>
</v13:RelationshipToken>
</tr:ActAs>
```

Plus there are minor differences here. I have two ways now I think:

1. If I can change old code to STS client send request with those value. which I tried and not succeeded.
2. They provide some code which support fetching SAML assertion token and proof token from STS client. If I can put SAML assertion token into my JAX-WS client directly then this problem is also solved.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated to us

Comment: How were you able to solve the issue? Have you chose any other implementation/protocol apart from apache cxf like apache axis? 
Can you write the steps/changes you made to implement the new version - STS v 1.3? Thanks

Comment: @junaid Yeah. I was able to solve that problem. Sorry I just see your question.let me know if you still that solution :D :D

Comment: Till now unable to solve the issue. It would be great if you post whole solution with in-depth details (wherever is possible) as an answer.

Comment: Actually for their actual wsdl does not work for java reason it can not recognizes encryption algorithm written in wsdl. So I need to modify that wsdl little bit and then use it. That's all.

Comment: Can you share the modified wsdl? Or what changes you did - in an answer? And you used wsdl2java (CXF) for java code generation?

Comment: actually there are two part: 1) to get token from STS. 2) use that token to send request to USI service of Australia (my case). For part 1 I used modified wsdl. you need to put sha256 in algorithm suite of STS wsdl as it stop accepting sha1. For part 2 you need use apache cxf to convert USI wsdl into java code. Sorry I can not share my code directly as I am bound to terms and condition for the company I work for. But I try to put enough information so that you can complete. Colm O hEigeartaigh is one of security expert apache cxf. His answer is very hard to understand but very useful.

Comment: Will you please take a look into this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60052573/an-error-occurred-when-verifying-security-for-the-message-saml-token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SHA-256 digest algorithm is normally set by using an AlgorithmSuite policy that requires it (e.g. Basic256Sha256). I see in the policy they are still using "Basic256" however. CXF allows you to configure RSA-SHA256 via some configuration properties (see for example 'ws-security.asymmetric.signature.algorithm' here http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html). You can set ActAs Object/Element on the STSClient directly.

Comment: I am not sure how to put ActAs Element in the client code.If you can give some more details way with example that will be great. And now I am overwriting default JAX-WS code to achieve this target. I mean that I am trying to overwrite their code.

Comment: See this configuration: https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/services/sts/systests/basic/src/test/resources/org/apache/cxf/systest/sts/username_actas/cxf-client.xml - the "actAs" property refers to a class https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/rt/ws/security/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/ws/security/trust/delegation/WSSUsernameCallbackHandler.java - this adds in a UsernameToken Element into "ActAs"

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will test that.

Comment: I just wanted to thank you for you answer. It took me some time to understand your answer. I needed to change AlgorithmSuite policity. Yeah ActAs can be set directly as element but to set that as element. I need to change some internal of class rt.jar to set element directly. But yes that was achievable. I should thank you earlier. But I missed that. It is not everyday while anyone get answer in stackoverflow from scholar like you. :) :)

Comment: @SabbirAhmedSourove, you changed the `AlgorithmSuite` policy for vanguard-STS wsdl or USI wsdl? And what algorithm(s) you used?

Comment: I changed from vanguard-STS only.  Though it should be changed via USI wsdl too  by issueToken element but as we are pointing STS client directly I changed vanguard-STS only as it overrides USI wsdl issuedToken.

Comment: I used SHA256withRSA in AlgorithmSuite

Comment: Will you guys please take a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60052573/an-error-occurred-when-verifying-security-for-the-message-saml-token ?

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving "An error occurred when verifying security for the message". Two changes that I had to make to resolve this while using Metro 2.3.1 -

1. In the STS wsdl, need to mention the signature algorithm like this ---

   sp:AlgorithmSuite signatureAlgorithm="SHA256withRSA"
2. In the USI wsdl, need to change the AlgorithmSuite to Basic256 from Basic256Sha256Rsa15